# INSERT DELAYED with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::insert()

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a few cases in my application that I would like to execute `INSERT DELAYED` rather than the standard `INSERT` to speed up the script performance. I have a script that inserts hundreds of rows and might benefit from that feature.

I've read that `INSERT DELAYED` hasn't been implemented yet in zend framework 1 ( http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9484 ).

Anyone knows on a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the PDO object through Zend. Something like (untested):

```
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getAdapter()->getConnection()->query('INSERT DELAYED...');
```

`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getAdapter()->getConnection()` Should be a PDO object.. once you have that you can execute any query you want.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping to use the insert() function somehow, but i guess I'll have to wait for it to be implemented in the zend_db component

Comment: INSERT DELAYED is a MySQL extension, so it is unlikely this will ever be added to Zend_Db (which is a DB abstraction layer).